# Using signalR for streaming alongside a microservice architecture

Tags: microservices, caching, message-queue, async, messaging

I have a cluster of micro services with an exposed search API serving a client app. I want to "stream" in real time the aggregated results of a complex search. The search will be kicked of by the client calling the search API which in turn adds a message to a queue. This will be picked up by an orchestrator service which will in turn make calls to 1 or many partner APIs.

My search API has a signalR hub which streams the results of the search in a way akin to [this example](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-samples/blob/master/StockTickR/StockTickRApp/Hubs/StockTickerHub.cs#L25). My question is what are some messaging strategies for delivering new elements from the orchestrator to the search API hub stream.

I have thought of two possibilities (there are undoubtedly many more)

1. The orchestrator loads elements into a cache which is in turn polled by the Search API, and new elements added to the stream.

[image]

2. The orchestrator adds elements to a response message queue, the Search API listens and adds new elemnents to the stream.

[image]

Which idea sounds more reasonably?

My idea was to have correlating ID for the search and response elements, making the cache implementation a bit simpler and potentially a bit easier to scale horizontally.

For the response queue, I'm not sure how you'd go about listening only for the items you want for this request / thread. Probably more of an implementation detail, I'm not sure.

Comment: What is your definition of "reasonable?"  The only difference between your two diagrams appears to be the part where you use a search response queue instead of a cache.  Have you given some thought to what the difference is and how it affects your project specifically?

Comment: I’m just looking at the usual performance and scalability trade offs. To be honest I just don’t know enough about messaging and need some direction. Originally I thought if I was streaming to the browser, why not take a similar approach between two servers using a socket connection.. and is there such a thing as a temporary queue that I can spin up for each specific request? Sorry a lot of questions, perhaps I need to rewrite this post

Comment: Some general advice: don't solve a performance problem you don't have.  Only solve performance problems that are identified by measurements.